# Can multiple pull requests be sent to pull github commits?

Tags: git, github

I forked a project, edited some file and sent a pull request to the main project's master, and edited something else and sent a request again.

However, for the third edit and commit, when the request is sent, the message says:

> Oops! There's already a pull request for `<myname>:master`  Try a different branch or view the pull request?

So we can send the pull request twice but not three times?  I thought the idea of git is that we can incrementally fix and commit, and send pull request for each fix and commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not send a pull request for a specific commit, but for a branch ... That's why it says on the top of the pull-request page something like this:

```
 rvanlieshout wants to merge 2 commits into maccman:master  from rvanlieshout:master
```

Also, if you make commits to your branch, they are added to the pull request. You can see this nicely if you look at a pull requests of a big project like [this one on rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3023). There is a bunch of lines saying "added a/some commit(s)".

If you want to open multiple pull-requests, you have to do this using different feature branches.

Comment: so one request is good for several commits.  Even if you send the request first and then make some commits later, you don't need to send the request again. -- Unless if it is a different branch, then you need to send a request again?

Comment: Sort of ... Once the pull request is closed or merged, you have to open a new one ... But as long as the request is open, yes, every commit and push to your fork will be added to the pull request ...